# Will the function wait for the asynchronous functions completion before returning?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Let's say I have these geocoding calls:

```
function myFunction(marker1,marker2) {
  var firstAddress  = null;
  var secondAddress = null;
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker1.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
    # if geocoding successful, set firstAddress
  })

  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker2.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
    # if geocoding successful, set secondAddress
  })
  return [firstAddress,secondAddress];
```

}

Let's say I call `myFunction`. The geocode call is asynchronous, right? So it will execute and return quickly, calling the callback on results. Will the geocoding have finished when I return the addresses? How could I ensure that both functions finished before returning?

Comment: That's what's meant by "asynchronous" - it happens outside the control flow of the original function call.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for clearing it up </ironic>

Comment: OK well the answer to your question is "no", and you can go figure out why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no. You will almost immediately get to the return line of `myFunction`, most likely **well** before the AJAX has completed.

Your best bet is to force geoCoder's requests to be synchronous. If you can't, then what you will need to do is set a global flag indicating when both requests have completed and wait for that flag to be set. If it is, then you can gather your data, construct your array, and return it.

```
function myFunction(marker1,marker2) {
  var firstAddress  = null;
  var secondAddress = null;

  document.geoCodeRequestCompleteFlag = 0;

  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker1.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
    # if geocoding successful, set firstAddress
  })

  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker2.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
    # if geocoding successful, set secondAddress
  })

  setTimeout( function( ) {
    document.geoCodeRequestCompleteFlag = -1;
  }, 15000 ); // -- ensure that we don't get stuck indefinitely

  while( document.geoCodeRequestCompleteFlag < 2 && document.geoCodeRequestCompleteFlag > 0 ) {
    // wait
  }

  if( document.geoCodeRequestCompleteFlag < 0 ) {
    return 'timeout';
  } else {
    return [firstAddress,secondAddress];
  }
}
```

Be sure to add a `document.geoCodeRequestCompleteFlag++` inside your `marker1.getPosition()` and `marker2.getPosition()` callbacks.

The downside to this, is that if your requests take a long time, the browser may kill your script.

Comment: Do you think this would be inefficient: `while(!functions_completed) { setTimeout(function() {},50) }`?

Comment: It would have more overhead than the while loop in my example, but it woud, be *very* slightly less likely to be killed by the browser.

Comment: By the way, why are you creating geoCodeRequestCompleteFlag on the document? Why not a local variable?

Comment: Ah. It's on the document in order to be globally accessible by your callback functions (marker1.getPosition( ) and marker2.getPosition( )) If those callbacks were local to `myFunction( )` then you would not need a global requestCompleteFlag var.

Answer (score 1):

If the geocoder lib is actually asynchronous the array would be returned before you have the actual data yes.

Two ways (that i see to solve this), make myFunction callback-based or force geocoder to be synchronous somehow

Comment: Yeah, it's a nice idea, but then I think I would have to make everything asynchronous

Comment: @Geo: Well that is usually the pain when you use async libs, but then go for KOGI's method of blocking it to sync

Answer (score 1):

no it wont.  you need to coordinate the callbacks of the two requests somehow.  One easy way to handle it is to call the same function in each callback, passing in the relevant address.  Maintain an array via a closure to keep the addresses.  When the array reaches the desired size, you know you can proceed.  Something like:

```
var allAddresses = [];

var coordinate = function(address) {
   allAddresses.push(address); // addAddresses is bound to this function via closure
   if (allAddresses.length === 2) { 
      // proceed
   }
}
```

you can then call `coordinate` in your callback to the google API.

Note that you will need to handle error conditions, but with the above template that should be pretty easy....